# Lines below image php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display one line of excerpt from posts beneath the images at the bottom of this website: 
http://www.wha2wear.com/
This is the php function used to get the images and the excerpt:

```
<div class="blog">
<h2><span>Sneak peak</span></h2>
<ul>
<?php query_posts('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=6'); if ( have_posts() ) :      

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<li>
<h3 class="short_title"><a title="Post: <?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php   

the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ShortTitle(get_the_title()); ?> </a></h3>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
        echo '...</a>';
        echo '</li>'; ?></a>


<?php endwhile; ?></li>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts were found.</p>
```

```
</ul>


</div>
```

The problem is on two of the photos the excerpt is showing next to the photo instead if beneath it...thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your display is dependent on the data. A blurb starting with `<br>` or `<p>` will wrap, otherwise not.  Wrap them in `div`s to make them line up properly:

```
<div id="imageDiv"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a></div>

<div id="blurbDiv"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
        echo '...</a>';
        echo '</li>'; ?></a></div>
```

You could also just force a line break between the two:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>
<br />
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
        echo '...</a>';
        echo '</li>'; ?></a>
```

Comment: hello, thank you for answering, I'm not sure what to put inseatd of imageDiv and blurbDiv, I'm still a rookie sorry

Comment: You can literally put those in as the ids, or leave the ids out. I usually give a unique name to each div in case I need to address it in javascript later, but in this case it's probably not important.

Comment: thanks, I tried both ways but it just messed up the styling: http://www.wha2wear.com/

Comment: Yes, there are some interesting css styles associated with your divs that are hosing everything. I have added an alternate, simpler solution :).

Comment: I just looked at it; take out the `align="left"` and `align="right"`

Comment: the problem is that if I remove that the image won't be positioned to the left/right in the post :(

Comment: Maybe make a separate copy of the image? Or at least call it differently without the `align`.